# Why can I sometimes not change weapons as a Heavy?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-heavy

I know that the Heavy requires some cool-down time (before switching weapons) after spinning his Minigun, but, sometimes, even if I wait a good 10 seconds, I still get the can't-change-weapons sound, which is very frustrating when I'm in a situation where I either need to eat my Sandvich or make a quick escape with the GRU. Why is this, and how can I ensure that I can switch from my Minigun to my Sandvich as quickly as possible?

I have also noticed that, if I try to change weapons immediately after spinning my Minigun, it takes significantly longer for me to finally switch weapons.

---

Answers to Meme Scientist's questions, to provide more context:

- Are you playing in medieval mode, or a gamemmode which prevents the use of guns?

  > No, I am playing on normal mode.
- Are you playing on Valve servers or community servers?

  > About 50-50. This happens far more often on community servers like Saigns.de, though (although I'm not sure what the server has to do with my inability to switch weapons). I should also note that my latency on all of these servers is around 30 ms (any higher, and I don't bother playing on that server).
- What are your keys bound to? It's possible you may have rebounded your quickswitch or individual weapon selection switch to another key.

  > - MOUSEWHEELUP := weapon 1
  > - MOUSEWHEELDOWN := weapon 2
  > - MOUSEBUTTON3 := weapon 3 (melee weapon).
- What weapons cause this issue? Do all miniguns cause this issue (ie *Huo Long, Tomislav, Brass, etc*)

  > This happens with all miniguns (and is independent of my secondary and melee weapons).
- Does the same issue occur in online and offline gamemmodes? Latency could be a huge factor; maybe you are lagging on a server, causing you to see that it takes nearly 10 seconds to switch weapons

  > No, they do not, but, as I've mentioned, I only play on servers where my ping is below 50.

---

Given this information, what could possibly be causing my inability to change weapons from a Minigun?

Comment: That sounds like a bug or something wrong with your controls. You should be able to switch as soon as your gun stops spinning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug [introduced last week](http://www.reddit.com/r/tf2/comments/2rs0xy/heavy_now_has_a_longer_weapon_switch_time/) (specifically in the January 7 update) that Valve has yet to fix.

It only affects trying to change weapons with the number keys/`slot` keybinds... mouse-wheel weapon changes/ `previnv`/`nextinv` keybinds are unaffected.

Comment: hmmm. This has been going on for quite a while, and it's not just a delay in changing weapons-- sometimes I cannot change weapons at all.

And, also, my scroll wheel is mapped to my weapons, **not** the number key.

Comment: This bug may be similar or related, but it's not the symptoms the question asker is experiencing. I'm experiencing the same. The bug you linked to simply lengthens the weapon swap time, whereas the problem the asker is having is that he cannot switch weapons at all sometimes. He will either scroll his mousewheel or select a number key and nothing will happen.

Comment: @Rokk He has his mousewheel bound to the `slot1` - `slot3` commands.  Which is why this says "number keys / `slot` keybinds"

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a variety of factors you have to consider here that you haven't fully addressed:

- Are you playing in medieval mode, or a gamemmode which prevents the use of guns?
- Are you playing on Valve servers or community servers?
- What are your keys bound to? It's possible you may have rebounded your quickswitch or individual weapon selection switch to another key.
- What weapons cause this issue? Do all miniguns cause this issue (ie *Huo Long, Tomislav, Brass, etc*)
- Does the same issue occur in online and offline gamemmodes? Latency could be a huge factor; maybe you are lagging on a server, causing you to see that it takes nearly 10 seconds to switch weapons

All these types of issues could be affecting the fact that weapon switch isn't working for you. If you could, could you update your question to provide more relevant information?